# How to off an event

Tags: jquery, events

I am hooking event like below

```
  $(document).on("click", "#project", function (event) {
          $('selector').toggleClass('hidden')
    });
```

At a point I want to off the event.
How can I do that?

Actually I wan to do off it just before I 'on' it.

This is to ensure that the event is never called twice

Comment: `$(document).off("click", '#project')`, your title answers your question!

Comment: why not use the... `.off` method?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: _"Actually I wan to do off it just before I 'on' it."_ That doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$(document).off("click", "#project");
```

Comment: Murali cheetaa.. nandi :)

Answer (score 3):

Write:

```
$(document).off("click", "#project");
```

[More info here.](http://api.jquery.com/off/)